# Labels are overflown by following elements

Tags: html, css, label

I started to write a part of a website where you have like 'internal links', so if you click on a label of a radio button the text and pictures change, but in the code I wrote the indicator bar, which shows you in which subtopic you are at and the text boxes themselves overflow the labels. I commented out several sections and changed multiple design options but nothing worked. What am I doing wrong? 
The CSS of the Labels is:

```
.subtopic{
    width:calc(100vw / 3 - 0.25vw);
    height:5vh;
    float:left;
    background:white;
    color:blue;
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-bottom:0.5vh white;
}
```

The Rest of my Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/kxh50236/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `clear:both;` to `.text` should fix the issue

Comment: thanks. (Giving you a fictive cookie) had to add it at #bar too